# Python String Extraction for football results

Tags: python, string

I have the following string:

```
"W-Leicester-3-0-H|W-Hull-2-0-A|L-Arsenal-0-3-A|L-Liverpool-1-2-H|D-Swansea-2-2-A"
```

What I would like to do is manipulate the string above so it returns the results of each game which is the first letter after each "|".  In this instance it would be WWLLD.

Many thanks in advance, Alan.

Comment: Does the question hold or does it not?

Comment: The question does hold but i keep getting   

Could not parse some characters: string|

Comment: Well what _is_ your correct string then? The one you have in your question would raise no such errors. We can't help you unless you let us.

Comment: Sorry Rishav, i'm not sure what you mean.  The string above is as it should be.  However, I can't seem to be able to manipulate it.  But then even if i just use a string of "ALAN" it is erroring so an issue my end.

Comment: What does `type(s)` give you, where `s` is your supposed string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 string = "W-Leicester-3-0-H|W-Hull-2-0-A|L-Arsenal-0-3-A|L-Liverpool-1-2-H|D-Swansea-2-2-A"
 result = ''.join([s[0] for s in string.replace('||', '|').split('|')])
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply but I seem to be getting the following error:   

Could not parse some characters: string| = "W-Leicester-3-0-H||W-Hull-2-0-A|L-Arsenal-0-3-A|L-Liverpool-1-2-H|D-Swansea-2-2-A"

Comment: So in your string happends to be more than 1 "|" ?

Comment: Gonna edit my post to give u other example of doing that.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, i am using this within a html page.  So the import re isn't working.  Think I should go back to the drawing board.

Comment: Ok, fixed the first answer to match both, single "I" and double "II".

Comment: still getting   

Could not parse some characters: string|

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125847/discussion-between-nf4r-and-alan-tingey).